# how can i add Admob Ads to my app in android

Tags: android

hi i just finish my app . how can i add the Admob Ads to my app , i have trying everything and it seems that there is a new way to do that with google play .. anyway if anyone know how is it step by step plz let me know how is it

My xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

   <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    />
```

and my java

i have nothing there about the ADmob

my Mainfest

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

i try to follow this tut

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

anyway i got no error but when i try to run the app i will get this  error

Unfortunately, windows has stopped

and my logCat say

```
    07-13 12:15:56.909: E/AndroidRuntime(1263):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): Process: win.example.windows, PID: 1464
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{win.example.windows/win.example.windows.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at win.example.windows.Main.onCreate(Main.java:25)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     ... 11 more
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/win.example.windows-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/win.example.windows-2, /system/lib]]
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
07-13 13:09:17.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok finally i fix it

First My xml should be this way

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"



 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4863046628273331/4657543401"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"

    />
```

and my java

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and main fast is

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and

u will get error when u add this code to the mainfest You can fix it by doing this

Eclipse -> import -> existing android code -> browse -> navigate to google-play-services_lib FOLDER (android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject).

then, on your project, control click -> properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported -> ok

after that it should work perfect

any help am here ^^